# OSX : list files that contains Author:XXXX then grep them to find how many methods they have

Tags: regex, macos, grep

I am trying to come up with script that will find how many methods/functions are in files written by specific developers.

For example I want to filter down files that contains Author:XXXXXX then I want to search them to see how many instances the contain -(void)test  (count the lines that start with or list the lines)

Thanks

Comment: `filter down files/then I want to search them` Is this a two step operation? Do you mean filenames containing author names?

Comment: Post example data, and what you like to get out of it.

Comment: As in most Coding IDEs the Author usually gets added as text in a comment in at the top of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
for F in $(grep -l Author *.txt); do echo $F; grep -c void $F; done
```

You might want to put some quote marks in various places to protect the file names from expansion...